# Как правильно сделать проверку авторизации

Tags: reactjs

Задача следующая, при переходе в админку, нужно проверить авторизован пользователь или нет, токен лежит в localstorage, async функция проверки валидации токена работает. в store redux есть переменная отвечающая авторизован пользователь или нет. Сейчас проверку делаю в useEffect в компоненте App. Хотелось бы вообще сделать проверку до рендера компонента App. Подскажите в какую сторону копать или что перечитать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз нужно до рендера, то лучше сразу запретить переход на эту страницу, скрывать кнопку. Если же используете React Navigation, то ситуация ещё лучше. Во время рендера вашей навигации просто для авторизованного пользователя и гостя делать разные стеки

Comment: React Navigation для native вроде ? не? А так спасибо.